# How can I pause between two functions?

Tags: python, function, pause

How can I pause between functions of `choice_f ()` and `draw_f ()`?

```
while keepGoing:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        keepGoing=False
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
            choice_f()
#I want a pause here.
            draw_f()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you can achive that quite simply using time.sleep(n).

as below:

```
import time

while keepGoing:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
    keepGoing=False
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
        choice_f()
        #Pause for 5 seconds Example.
        time.sleep(5)
        draw_f()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: NOTE: There's `pygame.time.delay()`. It makes your delay more accurate.

Comment: I did it. When I make this code, the function choice_f () is executed after a pause. I can not understand why the order of functions is ignored.
If I understand correctly. First, the function choice_f () should be executed, then time.sleep (5) then draw_f (). But I first run time.sleep (5) then choice_f () and draw_f (). Why I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Everything is working. I did it.  

import time
while keepGoing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            keepGoing=False
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
            choice_f()
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.delay(1000))
            draw_f()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```